# pusherchat-rails deploing to heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku

I am trying to create a chat application on heroku using

the following 
 https://github.com/tarnfeld/PusherChat-Rails

I have cloned it to my local

when i perform git push heroku master i get the following

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***

Any ideas? or has anyone installed this on heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine what is happening is that you haven't replaced your SQLite3 gem with PostreSQL in the Gemfile. As mentioned in [this section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#write_your_app) of Heroku's getting started guide, you'll want to swap out your SQLite3 gem with PostreSQL like so:

```
gem "sqlite3"
```

Will get replaced with:

```
gem "pg"
```

Additionally you can add environment scopes to your Gemfile so you can continue to work with SQLite3 on development...

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end'
```

... though Heroku does not recommend it.

[Getting Started with Rails 3.0 on Heroku/Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

Comment: Thanks Jon that solved my problem. But I now have another problem as when I go to the address http://deep-rain-3360.herokuapp.com/ I dont see the chat application

Comment: Are there any errors popping up in your console upon deployment?